# void pointer and different size of memory

Tags: c, casting

I have a function which converts a string of an unsigned int to its unsigned int counterpart.

I want to to be able to pass an unsigned type of ANY size to it as the container and specify a limit on how big of a value it is to hold. function prototype is this:

```
str_to_uint(void *tar, const char *str, const uint64_t lim)
```

`uint64_t *tar` is where the unsigned integer will be stored, `*str` is the string of the number and `uint64_t lim` is the limit of the size the `*tar` will be able to hold.

since `sizeof(tar)` is variable is it safe to cast `*tar` to an `uint64_t *` and then contain the converted variable in that? I know that it will always be smaller than the actual type anyway since I check for it with the `lim` variable.

is such a thing allowed?

basically it would boil down to this

1. I have a variable of an unsigned type where `sizeof(variable)` is 1, 2, 3 or 4.
2. I pass the variable to the function via `(void *)&variable`.
3. in the function I cast it to `uint64_t *` and write the detected variable into it. I make sure the detected variable is able to be written into the variable by checking if it is smaller or equal than `lim`

is this allowed?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int str_to_uint(uint64_t *tar, const char *str, const uint64_t lim) {
    char *eptr = NULL;
    unsigned long long int temp = 0;

    if (str == NULL) {
        printf("str is a NULL pointer\n");
        return -1;
    }

    temp = strtoull(str, &eptr, 10);
    if (temp == 0 && eptr == str) {
        printf("strtoull() conv err, %s\n", str);
        return -1;
    } else if (temp > lim) {
        printf("strtoull() value to big to contain specified limit, %s\n", str);
        return -1;
    } else {
        *tar = temp;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int ret;

    uint8_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint32_t c;
    uint64_t d;

    ret = str_to_uint((void *)&a, "22", UINT8_MAX);
    if (ret != 0) {
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = str_to_uint((void *)&b, "22", UINT16_MAX);
    if (ret != 0) {
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = str_to_uint((void *)&c, "22", UINT32_MAX);
    if (ret != 0) {
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = str_to_uint((void *)&d, "22", UINT64_MAX);
    if (ret != 0) {
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("a = %"PRIu8"\nb = %"PRIu16"\nc = %"PRIu32"\nd = %"PRIu64"\n", a, b, c, d);

    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: This will not behave as you desire on a little endian machine.

Comment: "is it safe to cast *tar to an uint64_t * and then contain the converted variable in that?" No, it's not. `tar` isn't guaranteed to be properly aligned and will cause you unaligned access problem. If you want the value, use [`intprt_t` and `uintptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer), otherwise object pointers can only be safely converted `void*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, of course you can't do that.

If I call your function like this:

```
uint8_t my_little_value;
str_to_uint(&my_little_value, "4711", sizeof my_little_value);
```

Then you do

```
uint64_t *user_value = tar;
*user_value = ...;
```

Boom, you've overwritten a bunch of bytes you're not allowed to touch. Of course you knew this since I passed you the size of my variable, and you say you "make sure", but I don't see how you intend to do that if your approach is going to be treating `tar` as a `uint64_t *`.

I don't see why you can't just return the converted number, like `strtoul()` already does. That puts the responsibility for dealing with mismatch between storage location and potential precision to represent the converted number on the user (or even on the compiler!) where it belongs. Your proposed API is very error-prone and hard to understand.

Comment: generally I did this because there is a high chance that I can call the function with `*str == NULL` and because I don`t want the orignal value to be touched if it can't be converted. Of course I could make temp variables outside of the function but really I am lazy so didn't want to do that

Comment: anyway I allready expected it wouldn`t work but maybe some magic I don`t know about could fix it without handling each one seperately

Comment: you can't simply say "I'm lazy" to avoid doing something. It may relate to security, safety... And don't use backticks for apostrophes `'`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I can, and I will if I don't have to do it. There is way too much crap code that could have been written in half the lines.

Comment: @mafso Thanks! I mis-remembered the details on that one, my own rule is to simply avoid all of `str*`. Edited, of course.

Answer (score 0):

At this line of code:

```
*tar = temp;
```

You are writing 8 bytes of data to a variable that may be less than 8 bytes in size.  You need to handle each size separately, like this for 1 byte:

```
*(uint8_t *) tar = temp;
```